# SQLALchemy: Get row elements based on columns key/name

Tags: python, mysql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

**What I am trying to do**

Using SQLAlchemy (with ORM) i am currently trying to create a function like:

```
export_database_table_to_excel_file( database_orm_object )
```

with a database_orm_object like

```
class database_orm_object(db.Model):
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_string     = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
```

The idea is to have an excel table generated  that prints the columns keys as a header row, followed by one row for each of the databases entries. As any database table may be given to the function, the column count and names are unknown.

**What works**

So far, I am able to create a table with a row of headers, for the example above the output would be an excel file containing two cells:

| id   | some_string |

This is done by fetching all of the database_orm_object columns and their keys. The keys are then appended to an (empty) excel file in memory.

```
def create_download_file(database_orm_object):
    book = Workbook()
    sheet = book.active

    col_headers = database_orm_object.__table__.columns.keys()
    sheet.append(col_headers) # add column keys as header row
    book.save("generated.xlsx")
```

**What doesnt work**

I dont know how to access the elements of a databases entry. My plan was to create two for loops, an outer loop that iterates through all the rows in a query.all() result and an inner loop that iterates over the database_orm_object's values. The inner loop appends the values to an array, the outer loop then adds this array as a table row on the excel file.

**Code**

Some of the code was already mentioned in *what works*. The two for loops have been added and are meant to iterate over the query results (outer) and each results values (inner). *col_id* and *query_result.col_id* are different types and are meant as an illustration of what i want to achieve:

```
def create_download_file(database_orm_object):
    book = Workbook()
    sheet = book.active

    col_headers = database_orm_object.__table__.columns.keys()
    sheet.append(col_headers) # add column keys as header row

    for item in database_orm_class.query.all():
        row = []                      # create an empty row
        for col_id in col_headers:    # ??? iterate over columns
            row.append(item.col_id)   # ??? add table row's value for this column
        sheet.append(row)             # append all the tables row values to excel file

    book.save("generated.xlsx")
```

**Question**

How may I access a query result row's element if I have the column keys stored in an array or list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in new version of sqlAlchemy:

```
for item in database_orm_class.query.all():    
    item = dict(item)
    # your code
```

Or for older version:

```
for item in database_orm_class.query.all():    
        item = item.__dict__
        # your code
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately, I end up in an "database_orm_class is not iterable" error. pip says, SQLAlchemy is up to date.

Comment: you can try `item = item.__dict__ `?

Comment: That worked! You just saved the last pieces of hair i have :D Thank you very much.